# If "not in Heaven", can Sanhedrin disregard or contradict a prophet?

Tags: halacha-theory, nevua-prophecy, sanhedrin

It is a [Mitzvah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foundations_of_the_Torah.8.2?lang=he&p2=Deuteronomy.18.15&lang2=he&aliyot2=0&w2=Mishneh%20Torah,%20Positive%20Mitzvot&lang3=he) to listen to a prophet (non-capital) and it is a Mitzvah to listen to the Sanhedrin (capital).

While it's accepted that a prophet can't establish new Halochos, he can command on numerous things. In all those things is Sanhedrin obligated to listen to the Navi just like all others or can they disregard or contradict him?

Comment: What makes the Sanhedrin different than any other Jew? What does not in heaven have to do with following a prophet?

Answer (score -1):

"Not in Heaven" means that Halachic decisions are not given by Heaven. If a prophet claims a prophecy dictating a Halachic decision we would not accept his prophecy. If his prophetic instructions are anything else then it would be binding on the Sanhedrin as much as on anyone else.

Comment: Thank you, but writing "Halachah is A" is not enough to qualify as an answer on this site. Please consider adding sources.